# Unity Rotation Won't Work on Y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I copied this code from a Youtube Unity tutorial video and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

When I play the game in unity and I try to look up with my mouse it tries to stop me from doing so.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour {

    public float movementSpeed = 5.0f;
    float verticalRotation = 0; 
    public float upDownRange = 60.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //Rotation
        float rotLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        transform.Rotate(0, rotLeftRight, 0);

        verticalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
        verticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotation, -upDownRange, upDownRange);
        Camera.main.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(verticalRotation, 0, 0);

        //Movement
        float forwardSpeed = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * movementSpeed;
        float sideSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;

        Vector3 speed = new Vector3 (sideSpeed, 0, forwardSpeed);

        speed = transform.rotation * speed;

        CharacterController cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

        cc.SimpleMove (speed);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'd better ask the author of the **Youtube Unity tutorial video**. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is it iust me or does he never assign the Y rotation?

Comment: @Wheremy if your question has been answered, be sure to accept the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you assign the Mouse Y value in verticalRotation instead of increment it.

Try something like:

```
float yAxis = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
verticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotation + yAxis, -upDownRange, upDownRange);`
```

Maybe you should also have a rotationSpeed like you have movementSpeed.

Comment: I don't think that's how it works, if the X works, then so should the Y. Mathf.Clamp clamps the value to stay between the other two therefor if Y is greater or lower than 60, it'll clamp to 60. That's the only reason for the Mathf.Clamp.

Answer (score 1):

If this script is on the camera itself then:

Here, try replacing your update with something a little simpler.

```
void Update()
{

    //Rotation

    float rotLeftRight = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    //transform.Rotate(0, rotLeftRight, 0);

    verticalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
    verticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotation, -upDownRange, upDownRange);
    //Only add the rotation when both values are set so you don't overwrite the first one.
    transform.Rotate(-verticalRotation, rotLeftRight, 0);

    //Movement
    float forwardSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementSpeed;
    float sideSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;

    Vector3 speed = new Vector3(sideSpeed, 0, forwardSpeed);

    speed = transform.rotation * speed;

    CharacterController cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    cc.SimpleMove(speed);
}
```

I believe your main problem was that you were setting Y to 0 when setting the X and then a little after you would set the X to 0 by setting the Y and since this is in the update, it was looking jittery and ending up with both at 0.